# Why am I getting an error related to linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic (3.13.0-53.88)?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, kernel, updates, dependencies

Every time I install or remove existing software I get the following error.

```
isuru@isuru-Inspiron-3420:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove  
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.  
4 not fully installed or removed.  
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.  
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic (3.13.0-53.88) ...  
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic)  

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.  
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.  
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already  

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic (--configure):  
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic:  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic; however:  
Package linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic (--configure):  
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:  
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic; however:  
Package linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic is not configured yet.  
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic; however:  
Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):  
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:  
linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.53.60); however:  
Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.  

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):  
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I didn't do any intentional kernel upgrades.
What could be the reason for this and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain on the cause for the error, but if you select advanced options during your initial load you should be able to select a previous image to load. I encountered the same issue and was able to load without an error with the last kernel image.

I posted this as a possible suggestion:

http://stephenjkennedy.me/?p=68

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same situation and I found this post that gave the clues to solve my problem.
In my case, what happened is that running the upgrade it tried to set the kernel 3.13.0-53-generic, and got the same issues. It wasn't a problem of downloading but configuring. My /boot partition had some space, but not big enough for the new kernel to get properly configure. Making enough space in /boot and running `sudo apt-get -f install` again, succesfully updated the kernel.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A) try `sudo update-grub` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` if it does not help then try the rest of the steps.

1) goto ubuntu terminal,

```
sudo synaptic
```

2) left hand pane, goto "Installed"

3) On the top you will see QUICK FILTER, type this "3.13.0" (without inverted commas), you will the linux images there, the issue that may have arise is because of the incomplete kernel download that could not be updated or you may have cancelled it, well, when you find the remaining packages and stuff in corresspondence to the linux kernel on which the error is coming i.e., 3.13.0-53-generic, you can then upgrade by:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```